# How do you search for columns in a SQL Server database by a string that the column name starts with?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have a SQL Server database that populates a datatable, which is the datasource for a datagridview control. I would like to hide all columns in the datagridview control that start with the string:

```
strColumnName = "Checkpoint " & intCheckpointNumber
```

How can I do this? I am using VB2010.

Where I have ended up, which obviously does not work is the following:

```
Do While intCheckpoint < intTotalCheckPoints
    If Me.datagridview.Columns ' I cannot figure out how to insert something along the lines of Name.StartsWith(strColumnName)' Then 
        'Hide this column with something along the lines of 'Me.datagridview.Columns(strColumnName).Visible = False
    End If
    intCheckPoint += 1
Loop
```

I cannot figure out how to hide the columns based on what their name starts with.

Thanks

Ok, I have revised my code, and ended up with the following:

```
Try
    Do    
        If m_DataTable.Columns.Contains("Checkpoint " & intCheckPointNumber & " Time") Then    

            Dim tabNewCheckpoint As New TabPage
            Dim dgvNewCheckpoint As New DataGridView

            tabNewCheckpoint.Name = "tabCheckpoint" & intCheckPointNumber
            tabNewCheckpoint.Text = "Checkpoint " & intCheckPointNumber
            tabctrlTimingTable.TabPages.Add(tabNewCheckpoint)

            dgvNewCheckpoint.Name = "dgvCheckpoint" & intCheckPointNumber
            dgvNewCheckpoint.DataSource = m_DataTable
            dgvNewCheckpoint.Size = dgvTimingP2P.Size
            tabNewCheckpoint.Controls.Add(dgvNewCheckpoint)

            strColumnName = "Checkpoint " & intCheckPointNumber
            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvNewCheckpoint.Columns
                MessageBox.Show(col.Name)
                If col.Name.StartsWith("Checkpoint") Then
                    If Not col.Name.StartsWith(strColumnName) Then
                        col.Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        intCheckPointNumber += 1
    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
    'MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
End Try
```

The problem that I have now is that the columns still are not hiding. If I insert stops in the program, I can see that the code isn't even processing the For...Next Loop. What would cause this?

Thanks

Ok, now I have changed:

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvNewCheckpoint.Columns
    MessageBox.Show(col.Name)
    If col.Name.StartsWith("Checkpoint") Then
        If Not col.Name.StartsWith(strColumnName) Then
            col.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

To:

```
For Each col As DataColumn In m_DataTable.Columns
    MessageBox.Show(col.ColumnName)
    If col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Checkpoint") Then
        If Not col.ColumnName.StartsWith(strColumnName) Then
            dgvNewCheckpoint.Columns(col.ColumnName).Visible = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

And it gives me an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but the datagridview columns have the same names as the datatable columns, so I don't see how this is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the context of the code?  Is `Me` a reference to a form or something?

Comment: Instead of looping over the checkpoint numbers, loop over the columns. `For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In datagridview.Columns...`

Comment: Thanks David, that was very helpful. I did edit my original post with another issue that has come up with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the line:

```
tabNewCheckpoint.Controls.Add(dgvNewCheckpoint)
```

Immediately below:

```
tabctrlTimingTable.TabPages.Add(tabNewCheckpoint)
```

Solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to hide columns in the DataGridView, I would use [StartsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx).

Comment: I figured that would be the best option. I edited the original post to show you where I ended up.